# What should a CRL file name look like when "new" and "delta" CRLs are generated?

Tags: certificates, public-key-infrastructure, certificate-authority, certificate-revocation

I suspect my Windows 20012 Certificate Server CRL revocation configuration is incorrect every time I generate a new CRL or a new Delta, only a maximum of 3 files are generated.

1. When I created the offline root (pictured below) it generated the file ``
2. When the offline root created its first certificate it signed with the name `Root01+.crt`

Partial Certificate Dump of what the root added to my certificate request file from the sub (policy) CA:

```
 2 Authority Info Access
     Access Method=Certification Authority Issuer (1.3.6.1.5.5.7.48.2)
     Alternative Name:
          URL=http://classic.freesmime.com/Root01/Root01_.crt
```

I then looked on the file system and noticed that the intermediate was referencing a cert that was never created.  So I went to the root CA, clicked on the node that said "revoked certificates" and hit publish.

I then had the choice to create a new CRL file or create a delta.  I wasn't sure which one do to do so I did both of them (this is a test lab). I noticed that the following files were generated:

```
 ROOT01+.crl  (updated for Delta and new CRL)
 ROOT01.crl   (Updated only for new CRL)
 ROOT01_.crl  (Never updated ... only created when CA installed)
```

**Question**

- So my question is.. is it correct that a given CA will have a maximum of 3 CRLs with a varying suffix as listed above?
- Is it correct that a underscore name is never updated?

For those who read this far, here is an image of my CRL configuration within a MSFT offline CA:

*Sorry for the large size, I'm on a Mac and think something is making the images appear too big*

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A "normal" setup with Microsoft's Certificate Services involves **two CRL files**: a *base CRL* and a *delta CRL*. The base CRL is destined to be referenced from a `CRL Distribution Points` extension in the issued certificate. The base CRL will contain a `Freshest CRL` extension which itself points to the delta CRL. Whenever a new base CRL is issued, a new delta CRL is issued immediately after; but the delta CRL can also be updated more often than the base CRL (and that's the point of using a delta CRL, by the way). By default, Certificate Services will force a new delta CRL whenever the previous one will soon expire, and also whenever a certificate is revoked.

You do not need more than these two files. Remember that a CRL has any value only insofar as clients (who validate certificates) can find them, and they find them by following the URL found in other objects. End-entity certificates contain one URL for CRL download, therefore the current CRL must always be stored under *that* name.

Furthermore, Certificate Services allows you to configure the names of both CRL (base and delta) only through a common setting, the two names differing only by the "`<DeltaCRLAllowed>`" keyword, which is replaced by an empty string for a base CRL, and a "+" sign for a delta CRL. That naming scheme is imposed; you cannot change it. (Incidentally, if you go for Web-based distribution of CRL and your Web server is IIS, then the "+" sign will cause you trouble; in order to allow IIS to serve the file, you have to activate [double escaping](http://blogs.iis.net/thomad/archive/2007/12/17/iis7-rejecting-urls-containing.aspx).)

For the third file with an underscore, verify whether it is a ".crl" file (i.e. a CRL) or a ".crt" file (i.e. a certificate). It is normal and expected to have a copy of the CA certificate in that location. The name for that certificate will be derived (still by default) from the host name of the CA, and its domain name -- if you get nothing after the underscore, then I suppose that your CA is not part of an Active Directory domain. The CA *certificate* is referenced from the `Authority Information Access` extension of issued certificates, while CRL are referenced from the `CRL Distribution Points` extension of the same certificates.